# Visual Basic FileSystem.GetFiles

Tags: vb.net, windows

I'm making a console application and I want to see what files is in a folder

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("c:\users\zac\desktop\booked vehicle\requested\")

            Console.WriteLine(foundFile)

        Next
```

after using this code and find that the folder is empty I need an If statement that say's

If foundfile has no files then
tell user no files found 
end if

but I don't know how to write this so Visual Basic understands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the files into a variable then check the count.

```
Dim files = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("c:\users\zac\desktop\booked vehicle\requested\")

If files.Count = 0 Then
  'tell user no files
Else
   For Each file In files
     Console.WriteLine(file)  
   Next
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileSystem.GetFiles()` returns a collection of file name strings.  As OneFineDay showed, you can use the collection's `Count` property to know if any files were found.

The downside of using `FileSystem.GetFile()` is that it has to search the entire folder before then returning the entire list of filenames.  If you are searching large folders and speed is an issue, consider using [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) instead.  That way, you can output a message if no file was found, otherwise loop throuh the list of found files.  For example:

```vb
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\users\zac\desktop\booked vehicle\requested\").GetEnumerator()

If files.MoveNext Then
  ' files were found
   Do
     Console.WriteLine(files.Current)
   Loop Until Not files.MoveNext
Else
  ' no files were found
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `Linq` to accomplish this. It's very quick and efficient to use in this case. I put the `Console.ReadLine()` at the end to show the files, you can remove this if need to be. Also you can change the `Console.WriteLine` to not include the string (s) if you don't want to. The s was declared if you want to show the files and also to see if there are any files. As I said, this was for my viewing to see the files. Straight to the point!

```
    Dim s As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, New DirectoryInfo("YOUR DIRECTORY").GetFiles().[Select](Function(file) file.Name).ToArray)
    Console.WriteLine(If(s.Length > 0, s, "No files found!"))
    Console.ReadLine()
```